# How to set date/time format during edit

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I set the date/time format and Input Mask in a field to display/input a 24 hour format Dec-28-2006 @ 12:12 but when I edit the field with an existing date it reverts back to Dec/28/2006 12:12:00 PM.

Format is set to "mmm-dd-yyyy @ hh:nn
Input Mask is set to ">L

I need to keep the field in this mode (Dec-28-2006 @ 12:12) when editing an existing date/time. Is this possible?

Comment: Is this field a text or date/time type? Why would you have an input mask that requires input of a single letter? Why do you need the @ symbol in date format?

Answer (score 1):

That is by design, and it takes a lot to make it behave differently.

You may get some inspiration from my two articles and their demo applications:

[Entering ISO formatted date with input mask and full validation in Microsoft Access](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/24659/Entering-ISO-formatted-date-with-input-mask-and-full-validation-in-Microsoft-Access.html)

[Entering 24-hour time with input mask and full validation in Microsoft Access](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/23539/Entering-24-hour-time-with-input-mask-and-full-validation-in-Microsoft-Access.html)

If you don't have an account, browse for the link: Read the full article.

Too much code to post here, but code is also on GitHub: [VBA.DateEntry](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.DateEntry.git) and [VBA.TimeEntry](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.TimeEntry.git).